# Jetpack Compose - DataStore interaction with Switch (preference)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack compose and I'm having a hard time.

I have a DataStoreUtil class which sets and gets a Boolean value. Default value is true (if not found).

```
class DataStoreUtil(private val context: Context) {

    // to make sure there's only one instance
    companion object {
        private val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore("settings")
        val FORCE_DARK_THEME = booleanPreferencesKey("force_dark_theme")
    }

    //get the saved email
    val getForceDarkTheme: Flow<Boolean> = context.dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] ?: true
        }

    //save email into datastore
    suspend fun saveForceDarkTheme(value: Boolean) {
        context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[FORCE_DARK_THEME] = value
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it works.

On the other side I have a Switch which should manage this Boolean value.

```
val value = dataStoreUtil.getForceDarkTheme.collectAsState(initial = true).value
var checked by remember { mutableStateOf(value) }
Switch(checked = checked, onCheckedChange = {
    checked = it
    scope.launch {
        dataStoreUtil.saveForceDarkTheme(checked)
    }
})
```

Saving this value via Switch works but not initial state, which is ALWAYS set to true on screen open.

I guess it's because collectAsState(initial = true) but... how can achieve this goal? (Have it set to false if DataStoreUtil returns false.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to read the value synchronously when you start the app, using `runBlocking`.

```
fun getForceDarkThemeSync() = runBlocking {
    getForceDarkTheme.first()
}
```

Edit: if you want to hold the splash screen until you have read the data and made a determination on whether to use light or dark mode, check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#suspend-drawing).

Comment: Thank you, it works but... Is there no other choice?

Comment: Not really, you could display a placeholder while you wait for the data read, but then you have to decide if you want a light or dark placeholder, so you end up in the same spot. For Android 12+, you can hold displaying any frame on the app until you have read the data, but applies only to the latest version.